# Can't get elements from DOM object variable with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, dom, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to do some basic scraping through Puppeteer.  In particular, I want to extract the text content of the `foo` div in the following layout :

```
<div class="foobar">
  <div class="foo">…</div>
</div>
```

This works :

```
const foobar = page.$eval('.foobar foo', (el => el.textContent));
const [foo] = await Promise.all([foobar]);
console.log(foo);
```

However I would like to extract the element from a variable containing a DOM object.  Reading [Puppeteer's ElementHandle class documentation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle) I would expect this to have the same result :

```
const foobar = page.$('.foobar');
const [bar] = await Promise.all([foobar]);
const foo = bar.$eval('.foo', (el => el.textContent));
console.log(foo);
```

However all I get from the `console.log(foo)` is

> Promise { <pending> }

and the script hangs, or if I close the Puppeteer browser it fails with

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection

What am I missing ?

Comment: Try `const foo = await bar.$eval('.foo');`

Comment: @ChrisG Forget my previous comment, I had `.text` instead of `.textContent`.  It works, please make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have missed `await`.

Should be:

```
const foo = await bar.$eval('.foo', (el => el.textContent));
```